# How to put TODO comments in xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, todo

I was wondering if there is a way to comment parts of xml code in android so they would later show up in  TODO list in android studio?
I am using android studio 0.8.2.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use XML comments `<!--` ... `-->` with `TODO` tags, e.g.

```
<!-- TODO remember the milk -->
```

Note that XML comments need to be at the tag level, that is

```
<!-- TODO ... -->
<SomeElement .../>
```

and not inside the tag like

```
<SomeElement <!-- TODO this won't work --> />
```

Comment: this is not showing blue sign in xml files as showed in java files

Answer (score 3):

**XML TODO comments** are now visible afterwards `Android Studio 3` in TODO list. To use them you can use it like below:

```
<!-- TODO Pending task -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

> Make sure to use it above Element/View in XML and not in-between.

[image: See below image showing usages]